# Replace sub string using array key in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

Replace string using array

```
$array = ['name' => 'John', 'other' => 'I am working'];
$content = "Hi {name}, {other}";
//$expected = "Hi John, I am working";
```

I need help to create a function that will search for an array key name in a string and replace any instance the key name (with the curl brackets) with the array value and return the expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply create a function like this

```
function replace($content, $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $val)
    {
        $content = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $val, $content);
    }
    return $content;  
}
```

And call using

#### echo replace($content, $array);

This will work perfect for you

Answer (score 2):

Function:

```
function replace($content, $array)
{
    return str_replace(
        array_map(function ($v) {
            return '{' . $v . '}';
        }, array_keys($array)),
        array_values($array),
        $content
    );
}
```

Use:

```
$array = ['name' => 'John', 'other' => 'I am working'];
$content = "Hi {name}, {other}";
echo replace($content, $array);
// ==> Hi John, I am working
```

It needs PHP 5.3 or major.

Comment: Worked!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple approach using what you've provided:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val){
  $content = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $val, $content);
}
```

I am unsure if the format `"{$key}"` would work, as the curly brackets would likely need escaping, so I chose to use simple string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply loop through your array and replace everything?

```
$array = ['name' => 'John', 'other' => 'I am working'];
$content = "Hi {name}, {other}";

foreach ($array as $key => $replacement) {
    $content = str_replace('{' . $key . '}', $replacement, $content);
}
```